# Any lazy way to put your own local ros package under /opt/ros?

Tags: ros, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I have modified package for a real robot which requires access of the ports bellow 1024.

When I put my catkin_ws under the root, it is able to access the ports below 1024 to communicate with the real robots easily but when I put it under /home/user/catkin_ws it fails to access the port below 1024 even after giving the access rights to the built node binary file.

I am not sure if this is possible or not,
But I am looking to do something similar that happens when we do `sudo apt install ros-noetic-pkg-name` but locally. Is there any (lazy) way such that I can redirect the build of the package to the `/opt/ros/noetic`. May be with running some script? Or may be something else?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400574/any-lazy-way-to-put-your-own-local-ros-package-under-/opt/ros?/) by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2022-05-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-05-13**:
What do you mean by *"When I put my catkin_ws under the root"*?

You have made a mistake somewhere, because under linux, installing a ros package in /opt/ros/ does **not** give it permission to create a socket with a port number less than 1024.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-13**:
Perhaps the implication is that "putting it under the root" would require actual super user privileges. And if those privileges are then also used to start the binary, you'd essentially run that binary as `root`.

**Comment by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on 2022-05-13**:
I am not sure if it gives the access to the ports under 1024 or not. may be because I am running it after `sudo su` is giving access rights. I trid to run the rosnode with `sudo` using launch prefix but it didn't helped. I also tried  the suggested way of using `setcap` but it didn't went well. I also tried `authbind` and also to set the unprivileged port number start to zero. Nothing worked for me so far. Any other suggested way to do it?

I couldn't find any way so i tried running it under `sudo su` and putting it under `/opt/catkin_ws` and it worked.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-14**:
`sudo su` essentially starts a shell as the `root` user. So, yes, that would allow your application to open up ports in the system reserved range.

**Comment by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on 2022-05-15**:
Yes, I think I will have to continue with that, Although not a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's one way to do it.

1. Elevate the privileges to superuser and source the setup.bash of the workspace

   `sudo su` then `source devel/setup.bash`.
2. Install the package
   `catkin_make -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO install`

---

Originally posted by [Alex-SSoM](https://answers.ros.org/users/86099/alex-ssom/) with karma: 163 on 2022-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on 2022-05-13**:
hey, thanks for your answer. I will definitely give it a shot.

Do you know if I can find any documentation of your suggested method?

**Comment by [Alex-SSoM](https://answers.ros.org/users/86099/alex-ssom/) on 2022-05-16**:
See documentation: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/commands/catkin_make